# What is "subset of superset" principle?

Tags: c++

In [c++ core guidelines](http://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#S-introduction), it said

> These guidelines are designed according to the “subset of superset”
>   principle (Stroustrup05). They do not simply define a subset of C++ to
>   be used (for reliability, safety, performance, or whatever). Instead,
>   they strongly recommend the use of a few simple “extensions” (library
>   components) that make the use of the most error-prone features of C++
>   redundant, so that they can be banned (in our set of rules).

What is "subset of superset" principle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [cited paper](http://www.stroustrup.com/SELLrationale.pdf) explains it like this:

> 1. superset:  Add libraries to provide application-specific facilities, *then*
> 2. subset: Subtract features (outside the library implementation) to provide semantic guarantees
>
> The result is a subset of a superset of a language called a
>   Semantically Enhanced Library Language.

Answer (score 6):

Take a look at the [Keynote from CppCon 2015](https://youtu.be/1OEu9C51K2A?t=17m45s).
The concept is explained more precisely there.
[image]

The "subset of a superset" is an approach to gain better safety though libraries and static analyses; not through limiting current language features.

Answer (score 0):

In the reference Stroustrup05, he says:

1. superset:  Add libraries to provide application-specific
   facilities, then
2. subset: Subtract features (outside the library implementation) to provide semantic guarantees

The result is a subset of a superset of a language